# How not to read commas for some input values in read.transactions() in R?

Tags: r

I've a csv file and I'm trying to run read.transactions() on it as follows:

```
woq <- read.transactions("woq.csv", format="basket", sep=",")
```

when I did inspect() the out is:

```
> inspect(woq)
   items 
1  {D23, 
    DD,  
    RT,  
    ST}  
2  {D05, 
    D06, 
    DD,  
    RT}  
3  {D05, 
    DD,  
    PING,
    ST}  
4  {D06, 
    D115,
    PING,
    ST}  
5  {D108,
    DD,  
    FNP, 
    H/C} 
6  {D004,
    D22, 
    DD}  
7  {D22, 
    HTF, 
    RSTR,
    RT}  
8  {D215,
    D23, 
    PNG} 
9  {D05, 
    RT,  
    ST}  
10 {,    
    D10, 
    ST}  
11 {D06, 
    D17, 
    H/C} 
12 {D115,
    D17, 
    PNG} 
13 {,    
    D004,
    D10} 
14 {,    
    D06, 
    H/C} 
15 {,    
    NGR, 
    RT}  
16 {,    
    D214,
    D22} 
17 {,    
    D215,
    D22} 
18 {,    
    RT,  
    ST}  
19 {,    
    D10, 
    H/C} 
20 {,    
    HTF, 
    RTC} 
21 {,    
    D113,
    D214}
22 {,    
    D06, 
    D115}
23 {,    
    DD,  
    RT}  
24 {,    
    FNP, 
    NGRD}
25 {,    
    D215,
    PNG} 
26 {,    
    D05, 
    HTF}
```

And now if you observe the output, from the 10th record onwards (for 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 and so on) the output is starting with a comma(',').

Now, I'm trying to find out how to use read.transactions() without having that comma values in the output.

How to achieve this in R??